# encrypt particular excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel workbook with 3 sheets and want to protect only second sheet(sheet2) with password. 
I would like to when I switch to sheet2 from sheet1 or sheet3, it will ask a password and all cells of sheet2 are invisible unless password is confirmed.

Could you help me to do this task?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you have a read of these links please and reword your question:
  [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  Maybe recording a macro while activating sheet2, unprotecting it, doing things then protecting it again and moving to another sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple google search provided the following code from Microsoft..

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Dim MySheets As String, Response As String
MySheet = "Sheet1"
If ActiveSheet.Name = MySheet Then
ActiveSheet.Visible = False
Response = InputBox("Enter password to view sheet")
    If Response = "MyPass" Then
        Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets(MySheet).Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
   End If
  Sheets(MySheet).Visible = True
End Sub
```